# Rspec looking for route in specific controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

After I upgraded my app from rails 4 to rails 5 and rspec-rails from 3.0 to 3.6 when running specs after upgrade I get errors:

```
No route matches {:action=>"/login", :controller=>"posts", :session=>{:email=>"email@example.com", :password=>"password"}}
```

My route is defined like this:

```
post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
```

I'm trying to access it from my helper like this:

```
def log_in_as(user, options = {})
  post login_path , params:{session: { email:       user.email,
                                    password:    "password"}}
end
```

In my controller spec:

```
RSpec.describe PostsController, type: :controller,     posts: true  
do
  before(:each) { setup }
  def setup
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: 'email@example.com')
    log_in_as @user
  end
 #tests Code...
end
```

**Edit:**
rake routes | grep login Output:

```
sessions#new                login GET    /login(.:format)                                                    

sessions#create                   POST /login(.:format)
```

Comment: This definitely worked before the upgrade? I would have expected that you needed to do `post 'login' => 'sessions#create', as: 'login'` in routes.rb to create the `login_path` helper…

Comment: Yes, it worked before.. but anyway I tried to add this and still got an error.

Comment: The same error? Where is that log_in_as method defined? Can you also post the results of running `rake routes | grep login` from your terminal?

Comment: added the output. I couldn't add  'as: 'login'' beacause as you can see I have another route for login with GET, so I tried with a different route, ie post 'post_login' => 'sessions#create', as: 'post_login' and got the same error.

Comment: The log_in_as function is defined in an helper we use for several controller tests, and for each of them this error appears.

Comment: Looking at this again, I'm having trouble imagining how it could have worked before. The [`post` method in ActionController::TestCase](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActionController/TestCase/Behavior.html#method-i-post) takes an action, not a path. So, for example, if I create a test that says `it { get 'root_path' }`, I get the error `ActionController::UrlGenerationError:No route matches {:action=>"root_path", :controller=>"courses"}`. If you weren't getting that error in Rails 4, I think there's a missing piece to the puzzle.

Comment: did you ever get this sorted out?